# Ghostscript - clipping right hand side of page when printing to pdf

Tags: windows-xp, pdf-generation, ghostscript

I am trying to convert an excel 2003 worksheet to a pdf file.  To do this I have tried a number of the PDF converter/printers available (on 32bit Windows XP), including cutepdf, bullzip and pdfcreator.  Each one of them takes my file and removes the right hand side of the sheet.  See:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-z9BfHBPkLUOGVER21kNE1ROEE/edit?usp=sharing

I have another pdfcreator which works fine printing the page in it's entirety.  See:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-z9BfHBPkLUU2xCRWthWFNTMk0/edit?usp=sharing

The difference, between the one that works and the others (as far as I can tell) is that it doesn't seem to use Ghostscript, where as the others do.  My assumption therefore is that it is Ghostscript that is the problem.  It seems that the software is using version 9.05 of Ghostscript.  Bullzip offers the facility to use an alternative version and I have tried also using 9.07 with the same results.  The page size for the printer is set to A4.

Whenever I select one of the errant printers Excel's preview page shows the clipped image as if I am trying to print to a page size that is too small to fit the sheet on.  I have tried the following to resolve the matter:

1. Using fit to page option;
2. Setting page size to A3.

In the first case the image shrinks but is still clipped, in the second the image is shown only occupying the top left corener of the printable area but is still clipped.

However on opening these pdf's the image size/page size is exactly the same as the first example, ie appears to be 100% scaled image on A4 size page.

Can anyone help by:

1. Confirming this is a Ghostscript issue;
2. Assisting in determining what page settings are being used at conversion time;
3. Providing any solution and/or help in trouble shooting the issue further.

Many thanks

Regards

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the information provided its not possible to tell for sure, but this is likely *not* a Ghostscript problem. Ghostscript is dependent on the PostScript which is sent to it by the PostScript printer driver in Windows. This is dependent on the PPD file describing the 'printer'. Most likely the one being used has some hardware margin defined, and this is what is causing your problem.

You can change the printer to use the 'FILE:' port instead of whatever port it currently uses, this will prompt you for a filename, save it somewhere convenient. This is a PostScript file, if you post it somewhere public then more can be deduced.

If you can find the PPD file relating to the printer, then that also would be useful.

Hmm, actually looking at the images it 'might' be GS, since the total content is not clipped. I'd need to see the PostScript file though.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.  The ps file generated can be found at: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-z9BfHBPkLUSHZUNzFtYUZuVjA/edit?usp=sharing.  I will try and find the ppd file associated with the printer and report back.  Are you able to see anything obvious in the ps file?  Thanks

Comment: Got the file, I'll look at it after lunch :-)

Comment: Great - again many thanks.  The ppd file can be found here: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-z9BfHBPkLUX3p5OW8tTU02Rmc/edit?usp=sharing.  Thanks.  P

Comment: Well, the first answer is that it's not Ghostscript. The same PostScript file run through Adobe Acrobat Distiller produces the same result. So Windows/Excel simply isn't producing the clipped data. A possible problem is that the file is requesting an output resolution of 4000 dpi (!!!) Looking at the PPD the default appears to be a (much more reasonable) 600 dpi, did you change the resolution ? It looks to me like the excessive resolution has broken an integer in the driver, leading to clipping. I'd try putting the resolution back to 600.

Comment: Ken - That's fixed the problem.  4000dpi was the default set by the software.  Thought it was a bit weird but assumed it was correct.  Many thanks for all your help.  I'd've never figured that out!!

Comment: Ah, glad to be of service, very strange that it should be set to 4000.

Answer (score 0):

@user2177934: The file from your first link does use a page layout and page size of `842 x 595 pt` (A4), rotated by 0 degrees (that is: landscape, unrotated). This can be seen in the output of the following command:

```
 pdfinfo -box requisition_pdfxchange.pdf 
 =======================================
Producer:       PDF-XChange 3.00.0030 (Windows XP)
CreationDate:   Mon Mar 18 10:48:45 2013
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      841.889 x 595.289 pts (A4)
Page rot:       0
MediaBox:           0.00     0.00   841.89   595.29
CropBox:            0.00     0.00   841.89   595.29
BleedBox:           0.00     0.00   841.89   595.29
TrimBox:            0.00     0.00   841.89   595.29
ArtBox:             0.00     0.00   841.89   595.29
File size:      5057 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.4
```

The file from your second link does use a page layout and page size of `595 x 842 pt` (A4), rotated by 90 degrees (that is portrait, rotated so it looks like landscape).

```
 pdfinfo -box requisition_pdfcreator.pdf
 ======================================= 
Title:          requisition_wi_btn_v1.5
Subject:        
Keywords:       
Author:         Paul
Creator:        PDFCreator Version 1.6.2
Producer:       GPL Ghostscript 9.07
CreationDate:   Mon Mar 18 10:47:19 2013
ModDate:        Mon Mar 18 10:47:19 2013
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      595 x 842 pts (A4)
Page rot:       90
MediaBox:           0.00     0.00   595.00   842.00
CropBox:            0.00     0.00   595.00   842.00
BleedBox:           0.00     0.00   595.00   842.00
TrimBox:            0.00     0.00   595.00   842.00
ArtBox:             0.00     0.00   595.00   842.00
File size:      13773 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.4
```

Since you have installed the respective PDF file converters as printer drivers on a Windows system, my strong assumption is that you just mis-adjusted the driver settings for your use-case.

Just play with the landscape settings in your print job properties and all will be OK.  :-)

Comment: Kurt - many thanks for the reply.  It seems it was the 4000dpi setting that was causing the problem. I had assumed that as the print driver had set this itwas OK.  Clearly not :-)